# add a marker to google map wrt fix pixel distance

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

Can I add a marker in a google map at a fix pixel distance w.r.t. my location? As the document says, `LatLang` is only requirement for markers, but between the points I want to put a marker along the direction which is always visible on screen.
e.g. now I am putting a marker as:

```
    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latitude+.005, longitude))
            .anchor(0.5f,0.5f)
        );
```

which is ok for my default zoom level 17, but go out of screen as I zoom more.
Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like a job for the Projection class (fromScreenLocation)?  So something like compute the Point of the "my location" (using 'toScreenLocation') and a then a simple x/y (in screen pixels) delta and then convert that to LatLng using 'fromScreenLocation'.  The projection is obtained from map.getProjection().  Your solution will have to a bit smarter for edge cases and also must recompute on every projection change (map move/zoom).

Comment: I would try to create a bitmap, which is already "displaced" by some pixels, (i.e. its origin has an offset to the real content) and then set the position directly at LatLng. But don't aks me,  how to create such a drawable.

Comment: yes...I have tried the same way, bitmap is there. But, if I zoom/unzoom the LatLang value visible in screen will also change, right?

Comment: What I understood is the following: You want to show a marker slightly displaced from the real location, maybe in order not to hide the location by the marker. When you are zooming, the LatLng may move outside of the visible area. But that has nothing to do with the marker, which would still be displaced by the same amount of pixels, as you would no longer need to add .005 to the latitude. (The scale of the latitude changes, but not the scale of pixels)

Comment: yes, thats true. But, as far as I know, marker can only be placed as LatLang (.position does not take x/y coordinate of screen, if I am correct), isnt it?

Comment: There seems to be some misunderstanding. Maybe you explain in more detail what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

[Custom-Makers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers)

Sounds like something I made for a "contact section", on a website. Maybe this? :-)